# magento checkout page change stape order

Tags: php, magento-1.9

We need multi step checkout magento in following order.

1. Billing Information
2. Shipping Information
3. Shipping Method
4. Order Review
5. Payment Method

is any one help us? 
how can we do this?
what changes we need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to your checkout.xml file, inside 
`checkout_onepage_index` tag and modify there the order of your blocks, in

```
<reference name="content">
```

Also, you'll need to modify the steps order of the OnePage Block. Something like:

```
$stepCodes = array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'review', 'payment');
```

And in your controller, when saving one step you need to tell JS what new step will be active:

```
'goto_section' => 'shipping' (i.e.: when saving billing step)
```

Hope it helps...